# Exchanging max and limit

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, optimization

Suppose I have sequence of function $f_n$ that converge to $f$. 
Suppose I want to find maximum of  $f$ over some set $S$ that is 
\begin{align*}
x^*={\rm arg} \max_{x \in S} f(x)
\end{align*}
Unfortunately it happens that finding max of $f$ is difficult but finding max of $f_n$ is easy. So my question is the following true
\begin{align*}
x^*={\rm arg} \max_{x \in S} f(x)= {\rm arg} \max_{x \in S} (\lim_{n \to \infty} f_n(x))= \lim_{n \to \infty} {\rm arg}\max_{x \in S} ( f_n(x))
\end{align*}

I guess in general this is not true. Then was the necessary and sufficient set of conditions on $f_n$ and $f$ that this that the above is true.

For example, does the convergence have to be uniform or point wise is enough? Another question does $f$ have to be continuous or not?

I hope the question is interesting. Looking forward to your responses.

Comment: If you have a concrete sequence of functions in mind it is always better to deal with the original problem instead of jumping to generalizations of it.

Comment: I don't have one at the moment but I will try to find one. This resembles monotone convergence theorem or dominated convergence theorem. Except instead of integrals we have max.

Comment: No, I only mean that if this were not the original problem. If this is your original question then don't bother.

Comment: Consider the sequence of functions $g_n$ on $[0,1]$ that is $g_n(x)=0$ for $x\in[1/n,1]$, $g_n(x)=2n^2x$ for $x\in[0,\frac{1}{2n}]$ and $g_n(x)=-2n^2x+2n$ for $x\in[\frac{1}{2n},1/n]$. Then put $f_n(x)=x+g_n(x)$.

Comment: Maybe [the concept of $\Gamma$-convergence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CE%93-convergence) provides some useful hints

Comment: @user66081 thanks. Never seen this before. Will try to learn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For sure it depends on type of convergence.

Generally, it is not true. For example, define $f,f_n:[0,1]\to {\mathbb R}$ as $f_n(x)=\frac{x}{n}$ and $f\equiv 0$. Thus, $f_n\to f$, in many senses such as point-wise, sup-norm, ..., while 
$$ 
[0,1] = \arg\min f \ne \lim_{n\to \infty} \arg\min f_n = \lim_{n\to \infty} 0.
$$

Comment: So, when can we say that the limit and the argmax are exchangeable?

Comment: In fact, it was a counter-example for continuous functions and many form of convergences!

Comment: I would not say that it is a counterexample at all, because if $x_n$ is one possible argmax of $f_n$ (i.e. $x_n=0$), then $x_n \to x=0$ and hence the limit is (one possible choice of) the argmax of $f$. This should be generally true for $f_n \to f$ uniformly (if each $f_n$ is continuous), as long as one knows (or assumes) that $x_n \to x$ for some $x$. If you are working on a compact set, you can always assume this by switching to a subsequence.

Comment: @PhoemueX I do completely agree with your point however the question above is something else. Thanks for your comment